# local SMTP server won't send email from cfmail b/c of rcpthosts issue

Tags: email, coldfusion, smtp, cfmail

We've ported several legacy ColdFusion sites from rackspace to viviotech, and they all work fine except for sending email using the cfmail tag. When viewing the CF mail.log it contains this error message for each attempt:

"Error","scheduler-0","07/01/10","06:31:22",,"Invalid Addresses;   nested exception is:  class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.5.3 - chkuser) "

However, looking at the rcpthosts file, the domain is indeed there that was used in the "from" attribute of cfmail. going into the CF admin, you can set the SMTP server and verify connection. I have tried both 127.0.0.1 as well as the actual IP of the server--both verify as successful connections, but I still can't send email. The old server worked fine for this (even though CF is not supported by rackspace, but IS supported by vivio).

One advice I was already given was use the user:password@server.com construct, but I don't want to do that since none of these domains are reliably permanent--we are wanting to change most or all of the sites to PHP in the next year if possible. I just want to be able to use the local SMTP without restriction, as I was able to on the previous server.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found the key to the answer here: http://www.palomine.net/qmail/relaying.html

The new server we moved to uses qmail instead of sendmail, which has major restrictions on email by default. There is a "selective relay" link on this page that has steps to remedy, although it's an annoyingly large number of steps.